# Using compound conditions in my Crystal Reports SQL query

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to adjust my query to consider a compound conditional statement, i.e. :

```
({tablea.fielda} <> 5566 And Not ({tablea.fieldb} like '%889009%))
```

The initial problem was that Crystal would take that statement and remove the outside parenthesis and execute the statements independently of each other.  I thought I had a fix by putting the entire statement in a "NOT" statement and reversing the conditions, like so:

```
 Not ({tablea.fielda} = 5566 And ({tablea.fieldb} like '%889009%))
```

Although Crystal did reverse the conditions and keep the conditions grouped, it is now changing the center `and` to an `or`.

This is a report that was created before my time that I am just modifying, and as such, I dont want to create a view or stored procedure that would cause me to go back and change all of the fields in the report.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "executing the statements independently of each other". What's the problem with removing the outside parentheses? What problem is it causing specifically?

Comment: There are items that are coded as "5566" that do not have the "889009" code attached to it and vice versa, the items I need to exclude from the report are those few that have both the "5566" code and the "889009" code attached to them.  So, if crystal executes these lines seperate from the other, it excludes all "5566" codes regardless of whether or not they are also coded as "889009" and vice versa.  Clear as mud?  :)

Comment: @EdwardLane: The original condition (ie. the first code snippet above) would also have excluded "5566" records *regardless* of whether they also had fieldb like "889009".

Comment: @MarkBannister:  I know, and that is not what I want.  I want an "and" statement, not "or".  Crystal keeps changing it, I dont want it to.  I want to know how I can stop it from doing that.  I dont know if I am not explaining my problem correctly or if it is difficult to understand if one hasnt experienced it first hand.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions.. I think we'll get it soon!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your second code snippet is (one of) the correct way to handle this.

`Not ({tablea.fielda} = 5566 And ({tablea.fieldb} like '%889009%))`

Crystal just reduces the statement via [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

`{tablea.fielda}<>5566 or {tablea.fieldb} not like '%889009%`

The logic is equivalent.

Comment: The logic is not equivalent.. The "or" indicates that either condition can be true for the entire statement to be true which is incorrect.. both conditions need to be met before the item is removed from the report as there are other items using these codes separately that need to stay on the report.  It is a compound condition that needs to be evaluated together so that if the entire statement is true, that item is removed from the report.

Comment: You know what, I just looked at it again and I can see why there was confusion, because I was confused.  lol.. I have mono and I guess its affecting me a little more than I thought.  Everything is good, I appreciate everyone that took the time to explain to me that I am an idiot.  lol